# Capistrano Deploy to EC2, User Permissions

Tags: amazon-ec2, capistrano

I have a rails app that I am trying to deploy to an ec2 instance using Capistrano. My `deploy.rb`:

```
set :application, "uc_social_server"
set :repository,  "septerr@bitbucket.org/urbancoding/uc_social_server.git"
set :user, "ec2-user"
server "ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com", :app, :web, :db, :primary => true
set :deploy_to, "/home/ec2-user/uc_social_server"
ssh_options[:keys] = %w(/Users/sony/.ssh/ec2-social-server-key.pem)
default_run_options[:pty] = true
```

Running `cap deploy:check` fails with:

```
The following dependencies failed. Please check them and try again:
--> You do not have permissions to write to `/home/ec2-user/uc_social_server/releases'. (ec2-23-22-188-11.compute-1.amazonaws.com)
```

I have tried some of the solutions I found on stackoverflow without success. What is the correct way to deploy to ec2 with capistrano?

Comment: does '/home/ec2-user/uc_social_server' exist? does your ec2-user have permissions to write to that directory?

Comment: yes the directory exists.

Comment: I ran ls -l and got:    drwxrwxr-x 17 ec2-user ec2-user 4096 Jul 29 22:42 uc_social_server. Not sure what d means, but the first rwx makes me think the user does have write permission (p.s. i have transferred file to this directory as this user before, so I am pretty sure this user has write permission to uc_social_server).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured out the problem.

`cap deploy:setup` by default makes root the owner of the folders it creates.

So before you run `cap deploy:setup` you must remember to add `set :use_sudo, false` to your deploy.rb (or the capistrano script file you are using).

If like me you have already run the setup command resulting in a `releases` and `shared` folders with root ownership,

1. ssh to your ec2 machine and delete these folders
2. add  `set :use_sudo, false` to your capistrano script (deploy.rb in
   my case)
3. run `cap deploy:setup`

Now capistrano should have created the `releases` and `shared` folders with the user you specified in your capistrano script as the owner.

`cap deploy:check` should now succeed.